# CSS & HTML Custom button position

Tags: html, css

i have a problem with positioning a button in a div inside a table cell.Are there any possible ways of getting the current div size(on which div user hovers over) and putting the button in the middle (Verticaly & horizontaly)?
[image: That's how the site appears atm] 
Hope you understand why i need to get the current div size and i do not have a fixed one.
 Thanks!

Comment: you need to post your code - HTML and CSS

Comment: _“Hope you understand why i need to get the current div size”_ – no, I don’t. Centering stuff using CSS only has been discussed broadly on the net already - and there are plenty of solutions for when you don’t know how big the elements are going to be upfront as well. https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/, https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could try to do that with flexbox?

Add your div where you have button certain properties:

```
.div{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```